# How to get FB likes from JSON file and update page automatically

Tags: json, node.js, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, socket.io

I was wondering how to fetch the "likes" of a fb-page through fb-graph and display them realtime on a webpage. I want to use socket.io, angular and node.js, but I am farely new to it. I got the information with this code, but I have to refresh the page, to get the new result. Can angular "watch" this URL?

```
request({
        url: "http://graph.facebook.com/justinbieber",
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: your question is very broad. is your issue only with streaming that data? or do you have other issues?

Comment: its just streaming. imagine a "REAL TIME DASHBOARD", where my company gets the number of likes of our fb-page "LIVE" and with sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/justinbieber', function(data){
            alert(data.likes);
        });                
    }, 3000);
});
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for? It updates every 3 seconds.